# mysql not found for installing wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install WordPress in my ubuntu 16.04 which requires MySQL while going with the process I am getting this every time after spending hours on this I still can't find the solution and while checking the MySQL it shows it is already installed.

```
 @root :~$ mysql​ -u root -p
    No command 'mysql​' found, did you mean:
     Command 'mysqld' from package 'percona-server-server-5.6' (universe)
     Command 'mysqld' from package 'percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6' (universe)
     Command 'mysqld' from package 'mariadb-server-core-10.0' (universe)
     Command 'mysqld' from package 'mysql-server-core-5.7' (main)
     Command 'mysql' from package 'mysql-client-core-5.7' (main)
     Command 'mysql' from package 'mariadb-client-core-10.0' (universe)
    @root:~$ mysql​: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed?

sudo apt install mysql

You can check installed packages using

sudo apt list | grep mysql

Comment: hey I have already mentioned that i have installed MySQL.

Comment: did you verified what is installed with sudo apt list | grep mysql ?